# updated ng-cli with working project now "Cannot GET /"?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I had a working ng cli project which had been created with the **beta.21** version of the cli. I wanted to update it to use the latest structure of the cli projects, so created a new project with the cli (**v.1.0.0**). I then essentially dropped the contents of my existing projects app file into the new project and went from there.

Strangely though, my new project builds without issue and produces the sizes and chunks I was expecting. If I run my express based backend which serves up the contents of the `./dist` directory, then my app works as expected. However, if I run `ng serve` I get the error `Cannot GET /` in the browser.

I really am not sure what could have caused this (my biggest suspicion is that my project has the file structure with `client/src/app` rather than the standard `src/app` however, I have changed all the references to the file path I could find and as the build is working, I assume that is fine)?

Any ideas / suggestions on how to debug further?

## Update:

`client/src/index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DemoProj</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

`.angular-cli.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "coty-monitoring-system"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "client/src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js",
        "../../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "client/src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "client/src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

browser network tab of failed request:

[image]

Here is the page source of what the cli returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is certainly odd.. index is served correctly, I wonder if the cli is adding a `<script>` incorrectly. Could you right-click on the page and select 'view page source' and post that source? I ask because `ng serve` serves from memory not from `dist` folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143245/discussion-between-ahmed-musallam-and-george-edwards).

Comment: I had same issue while working with ng serve. But in my case it was some permission issues with folder inside which the angular application was kept.

Answer (score 6):

Seems fine.
Probably you didn't run
`ng serve` in the project's folder.

When using CLI you have to run `ng serve` where app.module.ts lies
**usually :

> $ projectFolder\src\app

Comment: Hi Andre. In my case, I was getting this error because I wasn't running ng serve from within the main folder of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this issue if you `ng serve` from a sub-folder deeper inside the project folder. I just created a new component and forgot to go back to the project root before `ng serve`. As a result I got a 404 'Cannot GET /'.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem whenever I run ng s -o for the first time and there are TypeScript errors. Fixing the errors seems to fix it (regardless of whether the ts errors produce valid javascript or not)